# Passing variables into arrow function

Tags: reactjs

I think I have a misunderstanding of a coding issue with arrow functions. My code below is supposed to store in the variable "header" the returned jsx in the following bit of code. But it's not working. Am I passing in the parameters incorrectly?

```
switch (props.category) {
    case 'White':
      heading = 'White Advantages';
      break;
    case 'Black':
      heading = 'Black Advantages';
      break;
    case 'Neutral':
      heading = 'Neutral';
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  let header = (heading, advisorTags) => {
    if (advisorTags.length > 0) {
      return (
        <Typography variant="h6" component="h6" style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>
          {heading}
        </Typography>
      );
    }
  };
```

Comment: Is header a react component? How does the switch statement come into picture?

Comment: header is just a variable. You can see it where I have let header = ... The switch statement sets the variable "heading", which I then use in the arguments for the header fuction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, currently `header` is a function that accepts 2 input: `heading` and `advisorTags`.

If you want to store in the variable "header" the returned jsx you have to write something like:

```
const getMyHeader = (heading, advisorTags) => {
    if (advisorTags.length > 0) {
      return (
        <Typography variant="h6" component="h6" style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>
          {heading}
        </Typography>
      );
    }
  };

let header = getMyHeader(heading, advisorTags);
```

Comment: Right, that makes sense. In let header, you are passing in the values heading and advisorTags, while in the const getMyHeader, they are not values, but labels for the data you pass in. I'm trying that, but when I console log header, I get this weird output which starts off `$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)` but I was expecting the <Typography> text. Where do you think I might have gone wrong?

Comment: It's ok, I got it working now. I now know that it is jsx and not html that is stored in the variable, and the console log will look different as a result.